# GIT error in remote branch: cannot push or pull from existing remote branch

Tags: git

I am new to git, but I don't think I am doing anything wrong. gitk shows that the local branch is 1 step ahead of the remote branch:

```
branch1
|
|
remotes/origin/branch1
|
|
master-- remotes/origin/master
```

But when I do `git push origin branch1` it shows

```
error: failed to push some refs to <remote-url>
```

Although, `git push origin master` works. If I do `git pull origin branch1`, I get

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref branch1
```

Here is the output for `git remote show origin`:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <remote-url>
  Push  URL: <remote-url>
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
  Remote branches:
    branch1         tracked
    master          tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    branch1         merges with remote branch1
    master          merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Suspiciously there is a missing configuration for the local ref of branch1 for `git push`. Is that the problem ? How do I fix it ?

Comment: Perhaps the branch was deleted on remote? Do a `git fetch --prune origin` to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `branch1` is your local branch and it's not available in your remote repository.

If this is the case, then try the following command and see if it works:

`git push -f origin branch1`

Here, we are forcing to push `branch1`. Keep in mind it is risky if the `branch1` already exist in remote repository because it will override that remote branch.

Comment: the -f option works but.. I don't know why I need it. I made some more test-changes to branch1 and still I get the same error! how do I fix that ?

Comment: I was expecting it will be fixed after a successful push. By the way if it still exist then I am little bit puzzled. You can try these two command: `git pull --rebase` and 
`git push`

Comment: I did a git remote show origin. And it shows that only one (the master) local ref configured for git push. Is that the problem ? how do I fix it ?